# Online Addon Builder - How to display custom icon for the extension inside Firefox's Addon Manager

Tags: firefox-addon, icons, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

Online Addon Builder - How to display custom icon for the extension inside Firefox's Addon Manager?

I know that's a more general question and before I can even submit this someone is going to throw a link at me but I've been there trust me...

I've built my addon using the online addon builder but I'm not ready to submit it to AMO for review quite yet as I feel it needs more to be complete. I can't find specific information relevant to exactly what I want to do using to online addon builder. I've installed and configured the localized SDK that is utilized using a tool called cfx and of course theres tons of documentation!

The Question: What all notable values can be set using the package.json that determine how the addon is displayed inside Addon Manager? What notable material/configurations can't be set using package.json and how do I implement them?

I've removed all warning and errors from my code but I'm using a hardcoded path to a image whereas before I was passing it as an arguement within the PageMod object to a content script. Why? I'm not sure but I know one of you know how to configure the extension where I can specify chrome://ez-magnetz/data/icon16.png or somehing similar. Which is better than using a JUID in the path name that can change.

My widget has an icon but how do I specify a primary icon for the extension to be displayed in the AM? (package.json||chrome.manifest)

Using the latter of the two(chrome.manifest) how do I include that inside my addon so that its detected?(For the purpose of an Extension Icon using the online addon builder if possible)

Will someone please provide me with a chrome.manifest template for a basic addon?

Do I need the install.rdf and what has precedence over configuration is it like:
install.rdf>>>chrome.manifest>>>package.json
I noticed very similar settings amongst them.

I've been to XUL school I see that there is useful information it just seems outdated in the context of my addon.
I've read the basic info on the package.json and implemented simple prefs and of course the addon's description.

---

> My understanding is that I've created a bootstrapped addon using
>   Mozilla's Online Addon Builder.  Is that correct? The only thing I
>   wish to do now is to have a personal icon displayed for my extension
>   in the Addon Manager!
>       + I'd like to know how I may have and option for users to donate on AMO!

---

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an icon, just follow these two steps:

1. upload the icon you want to use to the data directory of your add-on, eg 'data/icon.png'
2. Add the relative path to the png file as an extra JSON property in the add-on info dialog, for example this:

{
    "icon": "data/icon.png"
}

See this screenshot for an example of what it should look like:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44296964/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-07%20at%202.15.49%20PM.png

*Aside: please only ask one question per post.*

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark your answer as accepted. I did however find this anwser on this site because I'm persistent and like I said above if theres a link I've been there ;)

Comment: Before I accept could you possibly address some of the other inquires listed above? Ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207033/changing-firefox-addon-install-icon

Comment: Sorry, If you're using builder the only option you have is to add properties to package.json ( unless you hand-hack the files in the built xpi, that way lies madness ). I answered the question in the title, if you don't accept it that's fine. At least for this very simple use case others will find this answer.

Comment: I would've just asked about the question you answered but I had so many and that would've been a lot of topics....lol Thanks for you help bro.

Comment: SO is full of topics! Add more! But try to keep each topic focused so that a given Q/A is as useful as possible to the community.